# Why is this loop not stopping?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, matrix-multiplication

First let me clarify the purpose of this piece of code:

**I need to find a matrix W that will multiply a vector X. WX (result of the multiplication) will multiply a matrix Y. The result of this last multiplication (YWX) should be as similar as possible to a vector Z.**

Hence, I have X, Y and Z, and need to find the matrix W that will maximize the similarity. My similarity function is working perfectly as far as I know; the problem is in the loop inside choose_w.

Now let me walk you through the choose_w code:

I create a zero (v x v) matrix w (v is a parameter). Then I create a control for the best matrix w found, called best_w (which initially equals the zero matrix). I create a variable called best_sim, and set it to -1, because that is the lowest possible similarity two vectors can have.

I then create a for loop what will run len(np.diag(w)) times. That is, the number of times it runs is equal to the length of the diagonal of the matrix.

Inside the loop, I create a variable called cont, and set it to True. While cont is True, the item in the ith row and ith column of w (that is, an item in the diagonal of w) will be increased by 0.1.

I call the similarity function to evaluate the result of this change. If the new similarity (new_sim) is greater than the current best_sim, best_w becomes the current w, and best_sim becomes the current new_sim.

Else (if the change does NOT yield a greater similarity), I change the variable cont to False. The while loop should stop.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import spatial

def similarity(w, x, y, z):
    x = np.transpose(x)
    z = np.transpose(z)
    wx = np.dot(w,x)
    ywx = np.dot(y,wx)
    result = 1 - spatial.distance.cosine(z,ywx)
    return result

def choose_w(v,x,y,z):
    w = np.zeros((v,v))
    best_w = w
    best_sim = -1
    for i in range(0,len(np.diag(w))):
        cont = True
        while cont:
            w[i,i] += .1
            new_sim = similarity(w,x,y,z)
            if new_sim > best_sim:
                best_w = w
                best_sim = new_sim
                print new_sim, best_sim
            else:
                cont = False
    return best_w, best_sim

b = np.matrix([[1.0/3.0,1.0/3.0,1.0/3.0]],dtype=np.float)
c = np.matrix([[2,7,4],[0,1,5],[1,3,6]],dtype=np.float)
d = np.matrix([[1,1,1]],dtype=np.float)

choose_w(3,b,c,d)
```

Comment: because `if new_sim > best_sim` is always True, did you add any prints in the loop to see what is happening?

Comment: Thank you, I solved the bug like this: "if new_sim > best_sim + 0.001"

Comment: You should always add either a maximum number of iterations or a minimal change rate in iterative optimization.

Comment: Also, as the code you pasted does not run as is, we have no way to help you debug it. Please consider posting a [MWE](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258849/760767)

Comment: I edited the code so that MWE is now included. As can be seen from the output the new_sim gets better and better.